# What is this purple tree?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have read about bugs [making things purple](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-yFCVb5Kmq8), but this solitary tree seems more intentional.  It does not have a name or interaction that I can see.

[image]

Comment: Where did you come across this tree?

Comment: @echoback - Alas, wanderlust has taken me from the area and I can't find it. It was a giant camp as you can see from the compass.

Comment: the bug making stuff purple usually happens when u have a fullscreen game and minimize it for a long time why that tree is purple idk tho however it ain't from the bug cuz that would make everything purple (at least in CSS).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's the sleeping tree!

If you find the cave nearby (with one giant in it) you'll find a body with a note that will lead you to Ysolda in WhiteRun.  Ysolda, after being shown the note and when asked, tells a tale about the origins of the tree.

Here's the map position of [Sleeping Tree Camp](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Sleeping_Tree_Camp), relative to WhiteRun.

[image: Sleeping Tree Camp Map]

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the tree at Sleeping Tree Camp, a giant's camp a fair way to the west of Whiterun, south of Swindler's Den . If you get in the right position near the tree's base, the option "Activate Sap Spigot" will appear. This will give you the potion "Sleeping Tree Sap", which adds 100 points to your health for 45 seconds. Also in the camp is an entrance to Sleeping Tree Cave, which holds a clue about something you can do with the sap...

Answer (score 2):

The tree is in fact a distant cousin of the hist trees from black marsh,ysolde comments on a tale that the tree is from some "floating island" also known as Umbriel, the tree also matches the description as presented in the novels by Greg Keyes, and like the hist, is capable of producing hallucinogenic sap that alters the users mind.

Comment: Very interesting. Some links to some of the terms you’re mentioning might help. Here are some that I found: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Books:The_Infernal_City, http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Books:Lord_of_Souls, http://www.imperial-library.info/content/infernal-city-lore-notes, http://www.imperial-library.info/content/lord-souls-lore-notes, http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Realm_of_the_Hist